# Header and Footer backgrounds in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers, footers

Is it possible, in Word 2010, to change the background colour in the Header/Footert, i.e. the document background is white and header/footer background green?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do so:

- In the "Insert" menu, go to "Header",
- Choose "Modify Header" at the bottom of the list,
- Go back to "Insert" menu, choose rectangle shape,
- Draw your shape as you want the header to be colored,
- Change the line color and the shape color,
- Important : apply "text over the shape" in the "Send backward menu" in the "Format" menu of the rectangle,
- Exit the Header modification.

Do the same with "Footer".

Note: there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Mamaxz works, however, when converting the document to a PDF file it can discolor and any gradient graphic will not convert and will leave white or colored space. In that case you can get away with backing a photograph. Or create the gradient panel in powerpoint and save it as a picture, then insert in word.

It may sound like a ridiculous work-around, but it works.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).